# CiviEvent Fees not displaying

Tags: civievent, drupal, online-registration

Using Drupal 7.7.1/Civi 5.26.1 I've set up a paid event with two price options (Waged/Unwaged), with no 'Pay Later' and Stripe as payment processor.

When I use the registration page for this event (test or live) in a logged in browser, the prices display OK and registration succeeds, but the prices don't display on the live registration page for a browser that is not logged in. All the other elements on the page seem fine.

Anonymous users' permissions to 'register for events' and 'view events' are set.

Log messages are

> Warning: array_intersect_key(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given in CRM_Event_Form_Registration->buildCustom() (line 550 of /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php)

and

> Notice: Undefined variable: fields in CRM_Event_Form_Registration->buildCustom() (line 550 of /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php)

I see in Registration.php @550 that this error may(?) relate to profile fields, but these seem to be displaying & filling OK.

Advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

When I modified the event to use a price set, it worked perfectly.